# What particle to use in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particles, syntax, sentence

I want to say “I like spending lunchtimes with Sarah.”

(Sarah is a fill-in name)

I am absolutely clueless, because I’ve only done Japanese for a semester at school (but I plan on choosing it as a subject next year). Would I use ‘to’ and where? I know lunch is hirugohan, but I’ve heard a variety of answers?

(Kanji and romaji are both fine.)

Some help would be much appreciated!

Arigatou gozaimasu!

Answer (score 3):

You're right that you use と for "with".

"[do ~~] with Sarah" → 「セーラ**と**[～～する]」

"Lunch" is [昼]{ひる}ごはん, but for "lunchtime" I think you can use 「ランチタイム」, 「(お)[昼休]{ひるやす}み」 (literally "lunch break". The お is a polite prefix), or maybe 「[昼休憩]{ひるきゅうけい}」.

I think you can say...

> 「セーラと｛ランチタイム/昼休み｝を[過]{す}ごすのが[好]{す}きです。」,
>   「｛ランチタイム/昼休み｝は、セーラと過ごすのが好きです。」, or
>   「｛ランチタイム/昼休み｝(に)は、セーラと[一緒]{いっしょ}にいるのが好きです。」

etc., depending on the context.

<sub>The の in 過ごす**の**が・いる**の**が is a nominalizer. It turns the verb 過ごす・いる into a noun form so that it can be followed by the particle が.

The は in the second and third sentences is a topic particle.</sub>